# Show that multiplication is open.

Tags: general-topology

I would like to show that the multiplication map
$$m:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},(x,y)\mapsto xy$$
is an open map.

**Attempt:** Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ be open. Then, we want to show that $m(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $p\in m(U)$. Then, $p=xy$ for some $(x,y)\in U$. Take $B_1,B_2$ open balls in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $(x,y)\in B_1\times B_2\subseteq U$. Then, it would suffice to show that
$$B_1B_2=\{b_1b_2:b_1\in B_1,b_2\in B_2\}$$
is open in $\mathbb{C}$. Is that true?

Comment: $\vert xy-x_0y_0\vert =\vert xy+x_0y-x_0y-x_0y_0\vert\le \vert x_0\vert \vert y-y_0\vert +\vert y\vert \vert x-x_0\vert.$

Answer (score 1):

You can use that for a fixed $x\ne0$, the multiplication $\Bbb C \to\Bbb C, y \mapsto xy$, is a homeomorphism, since it is continuous and has the continuous inverse $y \mapsto x^{-1}y$. The same way, the map $x \mapsto xy$ from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$ is a homeomorphism if $y\ne0$.
If now $(x,y)$ is in $U$ and $x\ne0$, then for some open $V\ni y$, $\{x\} \times V$ is contained in $U$. Then $m(\{x\} \times V) = xV = \{xv \mid v\in V\}$ is an open neighborhood of $xy$ contained in $m(U)$. In the same manner, you can handle the case $y\ne0$.
If $x=y=0$, then we can find an $x\ne0$ such that $(x,0)$ is in $U$, and then the method above produces a neighborhood of $0$ in $m(U)$.

This of course assumes that you are allowed to use that the maps above are continuous. If you would like to know how to show that, let me know.